# Icosaedro en PostScript

Tags: c++

Me dejaron de tarea crear un icosaedro a través de C++ (generar un archivo PostScript en C++). Ya tengo todo hecho, ya se grafica todo bien cuando lo veo en GhostView, solo que hay un punto que no logro poder programar en el mismo: me pide que calcule los puntos que marcan 1/3 y 2/3 de dichas aristas y luego encontrar la distancia mínima entre las mismas (obviamente la distancia mínima será de 1/3). En pocas palabras, lo que se busca hacer es crear hexágonos inscritos dentro de las caras del icosaedro, es decir, se busca que el icosaedro tenga forma como de balón de fútbol.

Aquí parte de mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Vector3D.hpp"
#include "Matrix3D.hpp"
#include "PS3D.hpp"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double fi = (1.0+sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;
    Vector3D ver[] = {
        Vector3D( 1.0,   fi,  0.0 ),
        Vector3D( 1.0,  -fi,  0.0 ),
        Vector3D(-1.0,   fi,  0.0 ),
        Vector3D(-1.0,  -fi,  0.0 ),
        Vector3D( 0.0,  1.0,   fi ),
        Vector3D( 0.0,  1.0,  -fi ),
        Vector3D( 0.0, -1.0,   fi ),
        Vector3D( 0.0, -1.0,  -fi ),
        Vector3D(  fi,  0.0,  1.0 ),
        Vector3D(  fi,  0.0, -1.0 ),
        Vector3D( -fi,  0.0,  1.0 ),
        Vector3D( -fi,  0.0, -1.0 )
    };
    int nv= 12;
    double eps= 1E-8;

    PS3D  p("icosa.ps", 400, 500);

    Matrix3D M= Matrix3D('x', 0 ) * Matrix3D('y', 0 ) * Matrix3D('z', 0 ) * Matrix3D('s', Vector3D(100,100,100));

    for (int k=0; k<nv; ++k) {
        ver[k]=  M*ver[k];
        cout << ver[k] << endl;
    }

    double d= abs(ver[1] - ver[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<nv; ++i)
        for (int j=i+1; j<nv; ++j) {
            double p= abs(ver[i]-ver[j]);
            if (p < d)
                d= p;           // calculamos el minimo de las distancias
        }                       // entre dos vertices

    for (int i=0; i<nv; ++i)
        for (int j=i+1; j<nv; ++j)
            if (abs(abs(ver[i]-ver[j])-d) < eps)  {
                p.mt( ver[i] );
                p.lt( ver[j] );
            }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Para que lo puedan compilar aquí les dejo un [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17HGekhbERAX0VD07aPW2JvZLP0EIpN_Y?usp=sharing) con los programas.

Sé que en el programa marco la distancia del vértice 1 y el vértice cero `abs(ver[1]-ver[0]` como la distancia tope por así decirlo, y luego se calcula para todos los vértices cumplan la distancia mínima, de ahí se obtienen las aristas del icosaedro. Lo que no sé cómo hacer es calcular los vértices que cumplan las medidas que les mencioné al inicio y luego graficar los hexágonos inscritos dentro de las caras del icosaedro.

Estaba pensando en poner `double r= abs(ver[1] - ver[0])/3;` como mi distancia tope y luego ir comparando con las distancias p para así obtener los vértices de valor 1/3, y por otro lado poner `double s= 2*abs(ver[1] - ver[0])/3;` para hacer lo mismo y obtener los vértices de valor 2/3 pero no resutó nada bien.